# how to add spot color channel to a tiff image use some code?

Tags: opencv, photoshop, tiff

I need to add an additional channel (with a custom name, not alpha) to a tiff image.
I'm surprised how difficult this is, because the tiff-secification says it is possible to add custom channels and PhotoShop is able to do it.
Now I'm looking for a way to automate it....

Does anyone know whether it is now possible with any code or any framework?

like this in photoshop:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtOzb.png

Comment: How about sharing one without the additional channel and one with the additional channel so folks can see what Photoshop has done? Maybe use Google Drive or Dropbox as `imgur` strips some things and doesn't allow some things.

Comment: `var channelRef = app.activeDocument.channels.add();` - it's in the javascript reference, p76